# Java Spring Hazelcast: Change Max Size of Map Cache

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I having a problem trying to implement a Cache to check what urls in the list are new, this is my Service Class:

```
package com.zimperium.server.phishing.services;

//all my imports

@Slf4j
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(value="urlcache.enabled", matchIfMissing=true, havingValue="true")
public class UrlCacheClient {
    private Cache<String, Boolean> cache;
    private String cache_name = "ReceivedUrls";

    //Constructor:
    public UrlCacheClient() {
        // Begin implementing Cache
        CachingProvider mycachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
        CacheManager mycacheManager = mycachingProvider.getCacheManager();

        //configure the cache
        MutableConfiguration<String, Boolean> config = new MutableConfiguration<String, Boolean>()
            .setExpiryPolicyFactory(AccessedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(new Duration(TimeUnit.HOURS, 72)))
            .setStatisticsEnabled(true)
            .setManagementEnabled(true)
            .setTypes(String.class, Boolean.class)
        ;

        // Get or Create:
        try {
            Iterable<String> existings_caches = mycacheManager.getCacheNames();
            log.info("Existing Caches: {}", existings_caches);
            
            if (Iterables.contains(existings_caches, cache_name)) {
                cache = mycacheManager.getCache(cache_name);
                log.info("Cache: {} Fetched (Already Existed).", cache_name);
            } else {
                cache = mycacheManager.createCache(cache_name, config);
                log.info("Cache: {} Created!", cache_name);
            }

        } catch(CacheException e) {
            log.info("Cache not available. Error: {}", e);
        }
    };

    //Methods:
    public Boolean isNewUrl(String url) {
        Boolean isnew = true;
        try {
            // If url exists:
            if (cache.containsKey(url)) {
                isnew = false; //if found in cache, not new xD
                this.datadog_client.Increment("CacheUrl.Hit");
            } else {
                this.datadog_client.Increment("CacheUrl.Miss");
            };
            cache.put(url, true); //We store on Cache for next time

        } catch(Exception e) {
            this.datadog_client.Increment("CacheUrl.Exception");
            log.warn("Cache Failed to check {}, Error: {}", url, e.getMessage());
        };
        return isnew; // If something wrong appends... keep going
    };
}
```

**I launch Hazelcast Like this:**

docker run --name=hazelcast -p 5701:5701 --detach hazelcast/hazelcast:latest --build

BUT I have discover that after apron 45mb of keys I start losing data no matter if it was in less than 72hrs, I made this test to probe it:

```
@Test
public void CheckMaxSize() throws Exception {
    // Hash Generator
    String ORIGINAL_HASH = generateRandomPassword(50);
    this.urlcache.isNewUrl(ORIGINAL_HASH); // We put it on cache
    
    Integer counter = 0;
    Boolean still_incache = true;
    while (still_incache) {
        still_incache = !(this.urlcache.isNewUrl(ORIGINAL_HASH)); //Negation: not (isnew)
        // We add new Hash to increse:
        this.urlcache.isNewUrl(generateRandomPassword(25)); //We dont care the value
        // Some Feedback:
        counter += 1;
        if ((counter%250) == 0) {
            log.info("We succed loading: {} items on Cache...", counter);
        }

    }
    log.warn("We losted our Controller Hash after putting: {} new ones in cache", counter);
}
```

The generateRandomPassword Function:

```
public static String generateRandomPassword(int len) {
    String chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%&";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        sb.append(chars.charAt(rnd.nextInt(chars.length())));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I have discover that after 16k keys the controller is lost, but when I Increase the size of the password size to 50... it only take 8k keys to lost controller...
Test Log:

```
com.zimperium.server.phishing.services.UrlCacheClientTest > CheckMaxSize STANDARD_OUT
    2022-07-28 13:11:04.669  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:05.354  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:06.052  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:06.744  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 1000 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:07.391  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 1250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:08.048  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 1500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:08.667  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 1750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:09.305  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 2000 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:09.960  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 2250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:10.616  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 2500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:11.275  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 2750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:12.539  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 3000 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:14.879  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 3250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:16.008  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 3500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:16.865  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 3750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:18.090  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 4000 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:18.833  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 4250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:19.857  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 4500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:20.693  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 4750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:21.347  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 5000 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:21.996  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 5250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:22.682  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 5500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:23.426  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 5750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:24.224  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 6000 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:25.079  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 6250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:25.899  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 6500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:26.493  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 6750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:27.334  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 7000 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:28.320  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 7250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:29.285  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 7500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:30.310  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 7750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:31.460  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 8000 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:32.317  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 8250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:33.018  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 8500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:33.675  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 8750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:34.417  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 9000 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:35.062  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 9250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:35.688  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 9500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:36.294  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 9750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:36.896  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 10000 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:37.485  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 10250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:38.067  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 10500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:38.728  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 10750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:39.398  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 11000 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:40.076  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 11250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:40.783  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 11500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:41.457  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 11750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:42.110  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 12000 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:42.789  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 12250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:43.380  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 12500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:44.053  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 12750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:44.724  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 13000 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:45.327  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 13250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:45.986  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 13500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:46.661  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 13750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:47.324  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 14000 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:47.979  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 14250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:48.644  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 14500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:49.221  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 14750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:49.812  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 15000 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:50.446  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 15250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:51.086  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 15500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:51.722  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 15750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:52.384  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 16000 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:53.081  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 16250 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:53.732  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 16500 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:54.441  INFO 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We succed loading: 16750 items on Cache...
    2022-07-28 13:11:54.607  WARN 39907 --- [    Test worker] c.z.s.p.services.UrlCacheClientTest      : We losted our Controller Hash after putting: 16812 new ones in cache
```

How can I increase the size of my cache? I need at least 50k keys in memory on Hazelcast map to work...
Thank you very much for you help in advance <3

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices

Run more Docker images is best.
See [this guide](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/getting-started/get-started-docker#step-6-scale-your-cluster) for a guide. Depending on your networking you may need `hazelcast.local.publicAddress` to make them find each other, as each will be separate Docker images.

*Note* that a 2nd Docker image doesn't increase capacity if you have the default `backup-count=1`. You need at least a 3rd, but you can have hundreds.

Or increase the heap size on the existing process, but this will hit a limit very quickly. Once Java heap size gets too big, GC will kill performance.

45Mb of data seems very little to run out of memory. Is it an OOM you get ?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your time! I’m not getting a OOM. In the test after putting 16k keys into the cache map the first one “controller” is lost… even when it happens in less tan a minute and I have a TtL of 72hrs in the config. If I double the size of the keys it happens at 8k so I assuming a limit on the keys I can store and don’t know how to increase it

Comment: By default, Hazelcast does not limit the number. You can request data be discarded when a threshold is reached. This needs explicitly requested, and although not in the code you show may be inherited from configuration/code elsewhere. If you spin up Management Center this can show the configuration being used. Or if you can ssupply a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and we can investigate

Comment: Another possibilty is that your `generateRandomPassword` generates the same key more than once. Although it looks good, it could be your random number generator is flawed. Why not try generating sequential numeric keys (1,2,3,etc) to see if it's that.